# RxJava3 : debounce/skip unwanted '0' in a flow of integers but want '0' only if getting continuously

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I have an Observable of Integer type which emits 0 and positive numbers and an Observer to catch the both.

Observable either emits continuous zeros or continuous positive numbers every 10 milliseconds(*One item at a time*).

*Like*   `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,6,7,8,8,9,10,11,4,5,6,5,0,0,0,0,0...` [expected]

Also it emits zero in between positive numbers (rarely).

*Like*   `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,6,7,8,8,**0**,9,10,11,4,5,6,5,0,0,0,0,0...` [unexpected]

I want to debounce/skip this zero coming in between the two positive numbers but interested in catching 0 if it is continuous.

Is there any operator combination to achieve this in rxjava. Thanks in advance.

Code looks something like this:

```
public Observer<Integer> valueObserver = new DisposingObserver<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer value) {
         //every 10 seconds a value is received
         //do action based on zero or non-zero values.
        }
    };

Observable<Integer> sourceObservable = Observable.just(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,6,7,8,8,0,9,10,11,4,5,6,5,0,0,0,0,0,...);
sourceObservable.subscribe(valueObserver);
```

expected o/p: 0,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,4,5,6,5,0

Consecutive duplicate elements I could eliminate by using distinctUntilChanged operator.

Comment: the zero in between is a sequence of 0 or your get only one ?

Comment: It may be a good idea to add examples of valid inputs and outputs. Please include the time and value of each item.

Comment: @bubbles Its a single 0 in between

Comment: from your update, do you need also to remove duplicates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires remembering how many subsequent zeros the flow has produced so far and emit nothing, one zero, two zeros or the non-zero item. You can do this with `flatMapIterable` but counting zeros is stateful hence the need for `defer`:

```java
static ObservableTransformer<Integer, Integer> skipSingleZero() {
    return source -> Observable.defer(() -> {
        AtomicInteger zerosSeen = new AtomicInteger();

        return source
        .flatMapIterable(item -> {
            if (item == 0) {
                int n = zerosSeen.getAndIncrement();
                // first zero we saw, don't emit it
                if (n == 0) {
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
                // the second zero in a row, it means a streak so emit both
                if (n == 1) {
                    return Arrays.asList(0, 0);
                }
                // third or more zeros, just emit those now on
                return Collections.singletonList(0);
            }
            // a non-zero item, reset the counter
            zerosSeen.set(0);
            return Collections.singletonList(item);
        });
    });
}
```

This is a sequence with one lonely zero in the middle so that should be skipped:

```java
Observable<Integer> source = Observable.fromArray(
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8,
        0, 9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
);

source
.compose(skipSingleZero())
.test()
.assertResult(
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8,
        9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
);
```

This has a 2-streak in the middle and should be preserved:

```
Observable<Integer> source = Observable.fromArray(
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8,
        0, 0, 9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
);
```

```java
source
.compose(skipSingleZero())
.test()
.assertResult(
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8,
        0, 0, 9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
);
```

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you. This is the perfect solution for my problem. Works perfectly!!!